# Apache2 dynamic vhost

Tags: apache2, vhosts

i would like use a partial dynamic vhost like that :

```
dev.[a-z0-9].domain.tld
```

I want to use it to develop some projects without having to configure a vhost each time.

This is a simple example to use :

```
dev.project1.domain.tld use /var/www/domain/dev/project1
dev.azerty.domain.tld use /var/www/domain/dev/azerty
dev.client1.domain.tld use /var/www/domain/dev/client1
...
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem :)

```
<VirtualHost MY_IP:80>
    ServerName dev.*.domain.tld
    ServerAlias dev.*.domain.tld

    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/domain/dev/%2/
    <Directory /var/www/domain/dev/%2/>
        Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/domain.dev.error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/domain.dev.access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

For use VirtualDocumentRoot enable apache2 mod vhost_alias